# Dingo/api throttle 500 status code

Tags: throttling, dingo-api

When I use **throttle** middleware, the connection resets several times and finally responds with a 500 status code, and the connection closes.
This program works nicely on my local host, but when I upload it on my VPS, it returns the above error.

Comment: Fixed syntax problems

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.